# Assigning multiple values to single variable(which is not a array) what is the behavior?

Tags: c

I see C statement in my code base where they have assigned two values to a single variable and the code compiles!! Example see below:

```
int var1 = VALUE_MACRO_HDEFINE,
    int_variable_already_assigned;
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Is this a valid syntax in C ?
2. What is the behavior of this statement ?

Comment: It will assign the second value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int var1 = VALUE_MACRO_HDEFINE,
int_variable_already_assigned;
```

This line/s of code declares **two** int variables, one called `var1`, and is assigned the value `VALUE_MACRO_HDEFINE`, and the other called `int_variable_already_assigned`, and is not assigned a value (meaning it will hold an unspecified value until it is assigned otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

#### Example 1:

This code will allocate two variables. `var1`, which will have a value of `3`, and `int_variable_already_assigned` which will have an unspecified value.

```
int main() {
    int var1 = 3, int_variable_already_assigned;
}
```

#### Example 2:

On the other hand, this code just causes compiler errors, because you're defining a variable that you've already defined in this scope.

```
int main() {
    int int_variable_already_assigned;
    int var1 = 3, int_variable_already_assigned;
}
```

Let's see those errors!

```
foo.c:3:19: error: redefinition of 'int_variable_already_assigned'
    int var1 = 3, int_variable_already_assigned;
                  ^
foo.c:2:9: note: previous definition is here
    int int_variable_already_assigned;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

#### Example 3:

Perhaps you overly condensed your code. In this case, we'd actually be using the comma operator. And in that case, I recommend you read any number of articles on stack overflow and elsewhere about that operator.

```
int main() {
    int val1 = 3;
    val1 = 4, 8;
}
```

#### Thoughts:

Look how helpful it is to have a complete compilable example. When we provide them, we can make authoritative statements about what code means.